# How to make the stroke width 1px in flutter's customPainter

Tags: flutter, canvas, stroke, custom-painting

I am building a Flutter app that allows you to draw pixel art on a canvas using CustomPainter. My `Paint()` method looks like so:

```
final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.deepPurple
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..isAntiAlias = false
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
```

Which gives me something like this (zoomed in):
[image: App Canvas]

After testing this I realized that that `strokeWidth = 1` does not mean 1 pixel. I can change it to `.1` or something, but that then seems to be doing sub-pixel painting. How can I get my stroke width to be exactly 1 pixel?

I looked through the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paint/strokeWidth.html) and I'm not understanding why this is happening.

Comment: Did you tried to set the isAntiAlias for true? I believe that this flag change the pixelate of the draw.

Comment: [devicePixelRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/devicePixelRatio.html) maybe?

Comment: @JRamos29 the anti-aliasing was the first thing I tried.

Comment: @pskink this may be on the right track, but I'm not sure how this relates to stroke width. Would you mind expounding on how I would approach converting this?

Comment: use `1 / devicePixelRatio` as a stroke width

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
Paint paint = Paint() ..color = Colors.red ..strokeWidth = 2 ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round ;
```